# c++ template putting implemetation into source file instead of a header

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, header, implementation

So as the title reads, i want to create a template class and put methods/functions implementations into the relative source file. After some research on the internet i found some perplexing solution with something about making an extra file and including it in the header.

I know that it is possible to place all the implementations inside header file and it will work just fine. Also a side question to that is: Is it commonly acceptable as the best solution to place all the implementations inside header or not because in a comparison to ADT in C you kinda want to hide the implementation in the source file, is it the same case right here?

A little example: Lets say i want a 2-D plane of dots that are characters and i want to use the following code.

## Point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H_
#define POINT_H_

template <class T>
class Point {
    T* x;
    T* y;
public:
    Point();
};

#endif
```

## Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.h"

template <class T>
Point<T>::Point(){
    x=new T;
    y=new T;
}
```

Comment: NathanOliver i asked how to do it the other way and not why... Thank you.

Comment: The top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) tells you why and how you can split the implementation from the header file.

Comment: You can explicitly instantiate in cpp file, and only those types would be usable.

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question, I am slightly confused by what you are asking....

Comment: In this case the problem would go away if you stored `T`s in the class, instead of pointers...

Comment: All i've wanted is an upvote for a question to get the student badge to be able to upvote others...

Comment: Actually, **what** *is* your question?

Comment: TL:DR would be: How to write Template classes in 2 separate files aka source and header.